# FastAPI Endpoint throws error when GET method is used

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, fastapi

I have been working to implement JWT Tokens in FastAPI. I tried to setup an enpoint that will extra user data i.e. username, from an access_toke. I initially setup the endpoint with the GET method but it kept giving me the error:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "user_id"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid integer",
      "type": "type_error.integer"
    }
  ]
}
```

After several hours of testing I tried many things and noticed the endpoint would work when the method is set to POST. This is strange to me as the dependancies used is the same and the endpoint is returning data, also when I post no data is sent. The token is passed correctly but in debugging I noted the endpoint immidiately raises the error:

```
"Exception has occurred: RequestValidationError
1 validation error for Request
path -> user_id
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
  File "/home/travers/projects/PRMS-api/PRMS/db/db_setup.py", line 38, in get_db
    yield db
fastapi.exceptions.RequestValidationError: 1 validation error for Request
path -> user_id
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)"
```

This is even stranger since I am not requesting user_id in any path or dependency. Please see endpoint code below.

Endpoint definition (nb: issue happens when the method is set to GET):

```
router = fastapi.APIRouter(prefix="/users", tags=["Users"])
oauth_schema = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="/users/login")

...

@router.get("/info", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def get_info(token: str = Depends(oauth_schema)):
    try:
        print("Received token:", token)
        payload = get_current_user(token)
        print("Decoded payload:", payload)

        if payload.get("user_name") is None:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Invalid token",
            )

        return {"payload": payload}
    except JWTError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid token",
        )
```

Definition for get_current_user, function. Note this is in a separate module called auth_handler. This module deals with generating tokens hashing passwords and verifying passwords, etc:

```
def get_current_user(token: str):
    payload = jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
    user_name = payload.get("sub", None)
    user_role = payload.get("role", None)
    return {"user_name": user_name, "user_role": user_role}
```

I've used python debugging to ensure the token is passed correctly, I have used both swagger documentation and postman to test the endpoint, I have cleared both my browser cache and cookies. I have rewritten the function several times and ensured there are no dependencies or request body parameters that would raise this error.

Edit: Added get_db code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


DB_URL = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost/prmsv2"

engine = create_engine(DB_URL, connect_args={}, future=True)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine, future=True)

Base = declarative_base()


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Comment: The error is coming from your `get_db` function (specifically, line 38 of `/home/travers/projects/PRMS-api/PRMS/db/db_setup.py`), but you have not shown us that code in your question, so we're not going to be able to provide much help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I omitted it since it was not called by the function and does not do much. I have posted it.